# Strange Behavior with update_option

Tags: array, options

If I run the following code in the debug console on my WP install, I get the expected behavior:

```
<?php
$option = get_option('fun_options');
var_dump($option);

$new = array();
update_option('fun_options', $new);

$option = get_option('fun_options');
var_dump($option);
```

Output:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\... : eval()'d code:3:
array (size=2)
  'option1' => string 'lovely' (length=6)
  'option2' => string 'horrid' (length=6)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\... : eval()'d code:9:
array (size=0)
  empty
```

The option is overwritten. (It is set in a plugin I created to isolate this problem).

For the options set in another plugin, I get different behavior from what seems like the same procedure. I've tried emptying the cache and I've tried updating with a string and an array. For some reason the option values get updated to the first letter of the string in some cases and remain unchanged in others.

Please could someone explain what is happening here and how to successfully update my options in this situation?

```
<?php
$option = get_option('ga_events_options');
var_dump($option);

//wp_cache_delete ( 'ga_events_options' );

//$new = array();
$new = 'test';

update_option('ga_events_options', $new);

$option = get_option('ga_events_options');
var_dump($option);
```

Output:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\ga-plugin\wp-content\plugins\debug-bar-console\class-debug-bar-console.php(84) : eval()'d code:3:
array (size=19)
  'id' => string 'my_id' (length=0)
  'license' => string '' (length=0)
  'status' => string '' (length=0)
...

C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\ga-plugin\wp-content\plugins\debug-bar-console\class-debug-bar-console.php(84) : eval()'d code:13:
array (size=19)
  'id' => string 't' (length=1)
  'license' => string 't' (length=1)
  'status' => string '' (length=0)
...
```

Comment: Somewhere is filter `option_ga_events_options` or `pre_option_ga_events_options`, or `update_option_ga_events_options` or `pre_update_option_ga_events_options`, which filters option value

Comment: in weird cases like this I have sometimes given up and ended up just using `delete_option` followed by `add_option`...